# Database selection for Android app with payment integration

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am new to Android development and preparing my first app. But soon I am confused for which database I should choose between SQLite and MySQL for my android app according to it's nature.

**Here is basic details of my app:** User will register on my app and will pay one time fee for using it. I am thinking to do payment integration using PayPal. Later on users will deposit amount to their app account from their bank account and will able to send money to other app users. Similarly users will be able to transfer money from their app account to bank account.

As I read on internet that SQLite works on app level on particular user's installed application in his/her mobile phone. So data are stored in SQLite on that user's installed app and thus available only his/her mobile phone. While MySQL data are stored remotely (not in installed app in mobile phone) and can be manipulated and managed centralized from any installed android app on any mobile phone using web services (example : PHP web service).

Please advise for which database I should choose for my app and also correct me if I am wrong for SQLite and MySQL database's basic difference.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding database is not important where I store the second step is database if you want to store locally then it will erase after application data erase all the thing, So as per my understanding you need to store it on server or the web, Because it will help in lot of things like,

Like one is it will store permanently another thing you can analysis your earning also who pay or not,

So I suggest to store on the server or the web then you need to choose server databases like MySQL or MSSQL or any another.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,
You should use server's database with this case, i think. Because all of your app doing need internet connection.

And local database doesn't safe, it can be access by root user.

Answer (score 0):

As per your app scenario, you should use server database.
And the best online database is Firebase real-time database. I am preferring firebase because it initially free to use and provide more flexibility than other.